# How to reverse font percentages

Tags: css

How do I reverse a font-size percentage increase. If The font size has increased by 125%, then I would have thought that reversing it would require a font size of 80% (100/125 = 0.8)

However in this example, where I am using the resultant fonts em size to create a width, it doesn't work. why?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RgQeE/).

html :

```
<div id="base">
    <div id="row1">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div id="row2">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>    
</div>
```

css :

```
#row2 {
    font-size: 125%;
}

#row2 input {
    font-size: 80%;
}

input {
    background-color: #343434;
    width: 10em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would be correct, using `font-size:80%` will reverse `font-size:125%`. However the `input` tag does not default its `font-size` to inherit like most elements so they don't inherit them from their parents. To 'reverse' the font-size and set it back to normal, simply don't try set it to `font-size:80%`.

Hopefully this example will illustrate how it works:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8S2ug/2/)

[image]

**HTML**

```
test
<div id="base">
    <div id="row1">
       test <input type="text" value="test" />
    </div>
    <div id="row2">
        test<input type="text" value="test" />
    </div>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#row2 {
    font-size: 125%;
}
#row2 input:first-child {
    font-size: 80%;
}    
.eighty-percent {
    font-size:80%;
}
input {
    width: 10em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. The example was a simplified demo of my problem, in my case the font size has to be set, but I have solved it by setting a default font size for the input so that I can calculate the correct size for the second input.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually working as intended, it's just that the font size of `#row2` is 16px by default, but for the `<input>` it's only 13px.  125% of 16px is 20px.  When you specify the rule in `#row2 input` you actually cause the `<input>` to inherit the font size of its parent for that calculation.  80% of 20 is 16, so it appears bigger.  The font size of the input is not inherited by default.  You can fix this just by removing the `font-size` rule from that input entirely.

http://jsfiddle.net/RgQeE/6/